# How can I get vimperator to scroll more than one line using the j and k keys?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I've tried using the following:

```
:map j 3j
```

When I do this and reload the .vimperatorrc file, it actually starts zooming in the page I'm on. The funny thing is, if I type 3j on a page without any mapping, it works. I'm using Vimperator 2.3.1 with Firefox 3.6.3.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out:

```
:noremap j 3j
:noremap k 3k
```

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the scroll variable:

```
set scroll=3
```

Comment: Incorrect. 'scroll' sets the number of lines to scroll with <C-u> and <C-d> commands, not `j` and `k`.